# Making a touch event bubble through an element in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a canvas containing several smaller controls. If I drag my finger over them, they get selected. The ManipulationDelta or MouseMove events fire. All working fine.

But I want to display an image above these with a lower opacity. So I added a simple Image element.

My question is: Can I make it so that the image doesn't "steal" my events and that the element below the image gets all data. One image can cover several objects below so I cannot simply forward the event.

I can give you examples of where this is implemented on request, but avoid to publish it directly since it might be considered spam or advertisement.

Thanks

Comment: Don't have WP8 environment available right now, but does `Image` has `IsHitTestVisible` property? If so, set it to `False` and it will not "feel" touch.

Comment: I'll check that out as soon as possible and let you know it it works.

Comment: As a side note, for events like Tapped, if you want to programmatically choose to "ignore" the event, you can set the `TappedRoutedEventArgs` args parameter's `Handled` value to false before returning, which will let the Tapped event bubble up to the next UI element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set [IsHitTestVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property of the image to `False`.

From MSDN:

> If this property is set to **false**, a UIElement will not report any
>   input events, such as MouseLeftButtonDown, and cannot receive focus. A
>   routed input event that was originated by a different object can still
>   route to or through an object in the object tree where
>   IsHitTestVisible is **false**. The object where IsHitTestVisible is **false**
>   can choose to handle that event, or can leave it unhandled so that it
>   routes further up the object tree.